# How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{x-k}\cdot\binom{x}{k-x} = 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

How to prove this:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{x-k}\cdot\binom{x}{k-x} = 1$$
For all $x\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ and with $\binom{x}{r}=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)\cdot\Gamma(x-r+1)}$

It is obviously true for all $x\in \mathbb N_0$, because then, all the values for $k≠x$ become $0$ and the one for $k=x$ becomes $1$. But after a few random calculations with Wolframalpha, I think it should hold for all positive real $x$.

Comment: What does $n\choose r$ mean, when $r$ is not an integer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Perhaps a replacement of factorials with Gamma function values?

Comment: Does $\binom{x}{r}$ mean $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)\cdot\Gamma(x-r+1)}$?

Comment: @alex, that might be what OP means; let's see if we get a response.

Comment: @alex.jordan, yes, with $\binom{x}{r}$ I ment $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)*\Gamma(x-r+1)}$. Sorry, about that I was unclear.

Comment: If that's what you meant, could you edit your question so it says that? People shouldn't have to go through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Just a thought: as $f=1$ on $\mathbb{N}_0$, it is enough to show that $f'(x)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: With $\verb*Clear[k, x]; Sum[
 Binomial[x, x - k] Binomial[x, k - x], {k, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> x >= 0]*$, Mathematica yields
$$
\frac{4^x \binom{x}{-x} \Gamma (1-x) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 x+1)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }} = 1$$

Comment: @FelixMarin How do yo include formatted (Mathematica) code? Apologies for rookie question.

Comment: @Jan Enclose the code between $\texttt{\verb*}$ and $\texttt{*}$. For example, $\texttt{\verb*Binomial[6,7]*}$ yields $\verb*Binomial[6,7]*$. You can choose another char, besides $\texttt{*}$ expecially if $\texttt{*}$ appears in the included text. For example $\texttt{\verb@x*y@}$ yields $\verb@x*y@$

Comment: Let $\,s\in\mathbb{C}\,$, it seems that: 
$$ f(s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{s}{s-k}\cdot\binom{s}{k-s} = \begin{cases} \qquad1 &\colon Re\{s\}\,\gt\,\color{red}{-\frac12} \\ \text{divergent} &\colon Re\{s\}\,\lt\,\color{red}{-\frac12} \end{cases} $$ 
And could not fully determine the behavior on the line $\,\small Re\{s\}={-1/2}\,$, i.e. $\,\small f(-1/2)=0\,$.

Comment: @HazemOrabi, I think it is possible to modify my argument for $\operatorname{Re} x>-1/2$ as well, appealing to Abel's uniform convergence test. No idea what happens for $\operatorname{Re} x=-1/2$.

Comment: @zhoraster, I also think it is possible. As a starting point, one would notice the last integral: 
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos{z}\right)^{2s}\,dz\quad\rightarrow\text{converges}\quad\colon\space Re\{s\}\color{red}{\gt}-\frac12 $$

Answer (score 5):

For $x>0$, ${2x\choose k} = (-1)^k{k-2x-1\choose k}\sim \frac{(-1)^k}{k^{2x+1}\Gamma(-2x)}$, $k\to\infty$. Then the power series for $(1+z)^{2x}$ converges uniformly for $|z|\le 1$ by Weierstrass test; in particular, it can be integrated termwise. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{x-k}\cdot\binom{x}{k-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(x+1)^2}{\color{blue}{\Gamma(x-k+1)\Gamma(k-x+1)}\color{green}{\Gamma(2x-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}} \\
= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)^2}{\color{green}{\Gamma(2x+1)}\color{blue}{\pi} }\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\color{blue}{\sin \pi(k-x)}}{\color{blue}{k-x}}\color{green}{{2x \choose k}} = \frac{\color{red}{\Gamma(x+1)}^2}{\color{red}{\Gamma(2x+1)}\pi }\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathrm{Re}\int_0^\pi e^{iy(k-x)}{2x \choose k}dy  \\
= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)2^{-2x}}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\pi e^{-i x y} \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{iky}{2x \choose k}dy =  \frac{\Gamma(x+1)2^{-2x}}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\pi e^{-i x y} (1+e^{iy})^{2x}dy \\
= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)2^{-2x}}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\pi \big(e^{-iy/2}(1+e^{iy})\big)^{2x}dy = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)2^{-2x}}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\int_0^\pi  \left(2\cos \frac{y}2\right)^{2x}dy\\
= \frac{2\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\int_0^{\pi/2}  \left(\cos z\right)^{2x}dz  = \frac{2\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+\frac12)\sqrt{\pi} }\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(x+\frac12)}{2\Gamma(x+1)} = 1.
$$

Comment: Nice! Would you mind justifying all the convergence and the interchanging of the integral and summation?

Comment: Yep. I just came back attempting to add the binomial expansion for justification only to find I was too late. :-)

Comment: $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{s}{s-n}\cdot\binom{s}{n-s} = 1\quad\colon\,Re\{s\}\,\gt\,\color{red}{-\frac12}  $$ Thanks.